# Evaluating math in regsub

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to convert a string from 2 dimensional array to 1 dimension in Tcl.

Eg

```
lane_out[0][7]  -> lane_out[7]  
lane_out[1][0]  -> lane_out[8]
```

The initial string is read from a file, modified and stored in another file. Also, the input file has a lot of different kinds of strings that need replacement so the user provides the find and replace regex in another file.

I have successfully done this for simple strings that required no additional calculations. But I need help in executing expressions. I was thinking that I could have the user provide the expression in the file and execute that but I have not been successful.

User Input File:

```
lappend userinput {\[(\d+)]\*$ *}
lappend userinput {\[(\d+)]\[(\d+)]$ [expr{\1*8+\2}]}
```

My broken code:

```
set line "lane_out[1][0]"
foreach rule $userinput {
  foreach {find replace} [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $rule] break
  regsub -all $find $line $replace line
  set match [regexp -all -inline {expr{.*}} $line] #match = expr{1*8+0}
  set val [$match] #supposed to execute what is in match
  regsub expr{.*} $line $val line
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is very complex: you have an input file, a set of search/replace rules, and produce some output. The rules, however, require calling `expr`.

Here is a made-up data file (data.txt):

```
lane_out[0][7] = "foo bar"
lane_out[1][0] = "foo bar" 
lane_out[1][1] = "foo bar"
lane_out[2][0] = "foo bar"
lane_out[2][1] = "foo bar"
```

And the rules file (rules.txt):

```
{\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]} {\[[expr {\1 * 8 + \2}]\]}
```

Here is my script (search_replace.tcl):

```
package require Tclx

# Read the rules file
set rules {}
for_file line rules.txt {
    lassign $line find replace
    lappend rules $find $replace
}

# Read the data, apply rules
for_file line data.txt {
    foreach {find replace} $rules {
        regsub -all $find $line $replace line
        set line [subst $line]
        puts $line
    }
}
```

Output:

```
lane_out[7] = "foo bar"
lane_out[8] = "foo bar" 
lane_out[9] = "foo bar"
lane_out[16] = "foo bar"
lane_out[17] = "foo bar"
```

## Discussion

- The rules.txt's format: each line contains search- and replace expressions, separated by a space
- The code will translate a line such as

  ```
  lane_out[2][1] = "foo bar"
  ```

  to:

  ```
  lane_out\[[expr {2 * 8 + 1}]\] = "foo bar"
  ```
- Then, the `subst` command replaces that with:

  ```
  lane_out[17] = "foo bar"
  ```
- The tricky part is to escape the square brackets so that `expr` can do the right thing.

Comment: In general, you apply a `string map` first so that any extra Tcl metacharacters don't cause problems. This can make the regular expression itself a little trickier to write, but is much safer.

Comment: Thinking about it, you might do `if {[regsub …]} {set line [subst $line]}` as a way to avoid having to use a `string map` here.

Comment: I like your second suggestion, will try it later today.